# Siddhi CEP consuming more CPU

Tags: complex-event-processing, siddhi, wso2-cep

I am using Siddhi CEP 3.0.2 as standalone library.  I have single execution plan with below stream & query definitions to correlate the consecutive events and detect the change. I am invoking custom function call. Object attributes mentioned in stream definition are custom java object and java.util.Map object types.

On every event occurrence periodically say 5 minutes, I could see CPU utilization is reaching around 40% to 50% for a second and gradually falls down. But this CPU utilization is increasing on every 5th minute.

Is something wrong in my way of using pattern query. Any help on this?

```
define stream portStream (source string,seq long, portInfo object); 
define stream deviceStream (source string,seq long, deviceinfo object); 

partition with (source of portstream, source of deviceStream) begin " +

@info(name = 'query1')
from (every e1= portStream->e2=portStream[e1.seq != e2.seq]) within 6 min "+ 
select e2.seq as currSeq, e1.source, 
custom:findPortStatus(e1.portInfo, e2.portInfo) as affecteddata "
insert into portStatusStream; 

@info(name = 'query2’) 
from (every e1=deviceStream-> e2=deviceStream [seq!=e1.seq]) within 6 min 
select e2.seq as curSeq, custom:findDeviceStatus(e1.deviceinfo,e2.deviceinfo) 
    as affectedDeviceInfo
insert into dStatusChangedStream; "

end;
```

Comment: I have the same problem. When I use the 'every' for pattern detection, I have a very high CPU-load and a poor event output. The processing take a long time.

Answer (score 0):

The increase in CPU utilization is expected. Let me explain this by example. If you have a pattern `every A -> B within 10 seconds` then for every arrival of event A and separate thread will spawn which will wait for B event for 10 seconds. In case there is no arrival of B event  within 10 seconds from the arrival of A , then event B is dropped. I have conducted many experiments in my research work and have seen similar behaviour. However the input streams I simulated had a constant inter-arrival time. So, the distribution of incoming stream is an important factor as it determines when A events are coming which creates a new thread and also B events that led to match.

In your case it might be the case that, a lot of A events came at 5th minute which lead to increase in CPU utilization. Also I would like to know, what method you used to compute CPU utilization.